# FloatWidget shifted when created

Tags: kivy, python-3.7

I'm trying to create menu.
I what that it will be called by right mouse click 
and it will be positioned where it would have clicked mouse button.
But it always shifted on some value.

What i am trying to do is to create a root widget, and menu widget that contains Bubble. When i click on right button, create new menu widget instance in current position by passing touch.pos in constructor.
As i find out it shift menu widget on same distance

```
Builder.load_string('''
<main_window_menu>:
    size_hint: (None, None)
    size: (160, 80)
    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'y': .3}
    BubbleButton:
        text: 'New'
        on_press: root.new()
''')

class main_window_menu(Bubble):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self._new = kwargs["new"]


def new(self):
    self._new()

class Menu(FloatLayout):

    def __init__(self, pos, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(pos=pos)
    self.show_bubble(**kwargs)

    def show_bubble(self, **kwargs):
        self.bubb = main_window_menu(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(self.bubb)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        self.bubb.on_touch_down(touch)

class Frame(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        print(touch.pos)
        super().on_touch_down(touch)
        print(touch.pos)
        if touch.button == 'right':
            menu = Menu(pos=touch.pos, new=self.new_operation)
            self.add_widget(menu)

    def new_operation(self):
        pass

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        tt = Frame()
        return tt

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are two problems with your code.

First, using the

```
pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'y': .3}
```

positions the `main_window_menu` inside the `Menu` instance to the right ('center_x':0.5) and up a bit ('y':.3). The `Menu` `Widget` is positioned at the `touch` coordinates, so the `main_window_menu` and its `BubbleButton` are positioned to the right and up from the `touch`.

Second, using `FloatLayout` for the base class of `Menu` means you are stuck with either absolute positioning of its children or using `pos_hint`.

So, I would recommend removing the `pos_hint` and using `RelativeLayout` as the base for `Menu`, then the default `pos` of `(0,0)` will place the `BubbleButton` at the `touch` position.

Here is a modified version of your code that uses my suggestions:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.bubble import Bubble
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

Builder.load_string('''
<main_window_menu>:
    size_hint: (None, None)
    size: (160, 80)
    BubbleButton:
        text: 'New'
        on_press: root.new()
''')

class main_window_menu(Bubble):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self._new = kwargs["new"]

    def new(self):
        self._new()

class Menu(RelativeLayout):

    def __init__(self, pos, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(pos=pos)
        self.show_bubble(**kwargs)

    def show_bubble(self, **kwargs):
        self.bubb = main_window_menu(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(self.bubb)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        return self.bubb.on_touch_down(touch)

class Frame(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        print(touch.pos)
        if touch.button == 'right':
            menu = Menu(pos=touch.pos, new=self.new_operation)
            self.add_widget(menu)
        return super(Frame, self).on_touch_down(touch)

    def new_operation(self):
        pass

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        tt = Frame()
        return tt

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Thanky,  your suggestion help to solve previous errors, but RelativeLayout block strarting event on button. I have try add in  Meny.on_touch_down()  touch.pos = self.to_local(touch.pos[0], touch.pos[1])  after that excute self.bubb.on_touch_down(touch). But it didn't help.

Comment: Kivy is pretty good at handling `touch` events. I think if you just eliminate the `on_touch_down()` method in `Menu`, then it will work fine.